# What is the right regex on kusto query language (KQL) to extract just the last part of a messages table?

Tags: regex, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to extract the last part of a message using KQL, the patter is consistent on what part of the message is needed, for example, I need to extract everything next to ">]" characters.

In the followed example, would be "Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.":

```
System.ComponentModel.SQLClientException (258): Unknown error 258 [Open]
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject,
   DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   [<GUI:03c09dfd-678f-45a1-a446-05f5217a705f>] Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.
```

I've been trying suing the followed regex patter but it fails with the message: SemanticException.

```
traces
| where ...
| project extract(@"(?<=>])",1,message)
```

Please someone advice.

Comment: You are trying to extract the part that follows `>]`. How does your match pattern reflect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [`parse` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator).

for example:

````
print input = ```System.ComponentModel.SQLClientException (258): Unknown error 258 [Open]
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject,
   DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   [<GUI:03c09dfd-678f-45a1-a446-05f5217a705f>] Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.```
| parse input with * ">] " output
````

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| System.ComponentModel.SQLClientException (258): Unknown error 258 [Open] at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) [GUI:03c09dfd-678f-45a1-a446-05f5217a705f] Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. | Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. |

Comment: I see, this is a totally different approach of what I was doing, let me try it, and I let you know. Thanks in advance.